# Pyinstaller everything works on local machine but fails on another

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, pyinstaller, tkcalendar

Having used Pyinstaller to build my application the `.exe` file works without problems on my development PC (Windows 10 64 Bit). If try to run the program on my other PC (Also Windows 10 64 Bit) I get an error:

[image: Error Message].

I have tried both onefile and folder option.

I'm using this Pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "C:/gui/exe/stopwatch.ico" --exclude-module _bootlocale "C:/gui/exe/rt50.py"
```

The code can be downloded from here: https://www.racetiming.dk/dev/rt50.py

I really hope someone can help me.

Comment: trying running the exe from command prompt and check the error.

Comment: That will require me to go back and use the onefile option as I do not want to install Python on the "production" PC. I will try this shortly and return.

Comment: I recommend you use autopy2exe as they making attaching a .ico file easy

Comment: I tried making a one file version and run it - but it gives no other error than the pop-up message :-(

Comment: @chess_lover - I have tried to use auto-py-to-exe but that generate new problems and won't even make the output file.

Comment: @hhartvig, just my 2 cents. If it doesn't work, then listen to the answrs

Answer (score 0):

Your app is trying to access a `"C:/gui/exe/stopwatch.ico"`:

```
root.iconbitmap("c:/gui/exe/stopwatch.ico")
```

It will not work on a machine that does not have such a file.
In general, hard-coding a path like that is not a good idea anyway.

The quickest fix is to just remove that line, but you won't have a fancy icon.

Comment: I do have (or want to have :-)) a fancy icon - can you suggest how to make this work ?

Comment: Look into how you can tell Pyinstaller to package that file along with your program, then figure out what the path to that file will be. (I recall something like `sys.meipass` in a Pyinstaller packaged program.)

Comment: I highly appriciate your help - but what I need is a explanation to the problem and guides how to solve. Maybe someone has their own development platform and can try to build the .exe file?

Comment: The problem is (a) you're using a hard-coded path to the icon file. That would only work if the person using installing the app puts it in exactly the right place. That's bad. (b) It's an external file that isn't automagically included by PyInstaller. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle explains how to add these external files and how to use them at runtime.